# Passing output of os.system function to another User Defined Function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am New to Python and am trying to pass an output of a In-Built function os.system to another User Defined function , when I try to store the result of the function in a variable and pass the same to the User Defined Function , it returns :

```
[root@sijr37wamxop570 ~]# /usr/local/bin/python3.6 Script_ICOS_Upload.py
  File "Script_ICOS_Upload.py", line 62
    multi_part_upload('570p', 'DB2Backup', BackupFile)
                    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

I have tried defining the below block into a function bkp() and then tried calling it main as well , but still receive indentation errors on cmd line :

```
cmd = "ls -lrt /home/db2inst1/TWS.0.db2inst1.DBPART000.* | awk '{print $9;}'"
BackupFile = os.system(cmd, shell=True)


    import ibm_boto3
    from ibm_botocore.client import Config
    import os
    cmd = "ls -lrt /home/db2inst1/TWS.0.db2inst1.DBPART000.* | awk '{print $9;}'"
    BackupFile = os.system(cmd, shell=True)
    #p1 = subprocess.Popen(["ls -lrt /home/db2inst1/TWS.0.db2inst1.DBPART000.* | awk '{print $9;}'"], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
    #BackupFile = p1.communicate()[0]
    #BKPFILE = print(BackupFile)
    #BackupFile = subprocess.call('ls -lrt /home/db2inst1/TWS.0.db2inst1.DBPART000.* | awk '{print $9;}'', shell=True)
    #BackupFile = subprocess.check_output(["ls -lrt /home/db2inst1/TWS.0.db2inst1.DBPART000.* | awk '{print $9;}'", shell=True)
    #BackupFile = subprocess.Popen(['awk', '/f89e7000/ {print $2}', 'syscall_list.txt'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    #BackupFile = Popen(["ls -lrt /home/db2inst1/TWS.0.db2inst1.DBPART000.* | awk '{print $9;}'", stdout=PIPE)


    COS_ENDPOINT = "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.net/" 
    COS_API_KEY_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" # eg "W00YiRnLW4a3fTjMB-oiB-2ySfTrFBIQQWanc--P3byk"
    COS_AUTH_ENDPOINT = "https://XXXXXXXXXXX/identity/token"
    COS_RESOURCE_CRN = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" # eg "crn:v1:bluemix:public:cloud-object-storage:global:a/3bf0d9003abfb5d29761c3e97696b71c:d6f04d83-6c4f-4a62-a165-696756d63903::"

    # Create resource
    cos = ibm_boto3.resource("s3",
        ibm_api_key_id=COS_API_KEY_ID,
        ibm_service_instance_id=COS_RESOURCE_CRN,
        ibm_auth_endpoint=COS_AUTH_ENDPOINT,
        config=Config(signature_version="oauth"),
        endpoint_url=COS_ENDPOINT
    )
    def multi_part_upload(bucket_name, item_name, file_path):
        try:
            print("Starting file transfer for {0} to bucket: {1}\n".format(item_name, bucket_name))
            # set 20 GB chunks
            part_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 20

            # set threadhold to 20 GB
            file_threshold = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 20

            # set the transfer threshold and chunk size
            transfer_config = ibm_boto3.s3.transfer.TransferConfig(
                multipart_threshold=file_threshold,
                multipart_chunksize=part_size
            )

            # the upload_fileobj method will automatically execute a multi-part upload
            # in 5 MB chunks for all files over 15 MB
            with open(file_path, "rb") as file_data:
                cos.Object(bucket_name, item_name).upload_fileobj(
                    Fileobj=file_data,
                    Config=transfer_config
                )

            print("Transfer for {0} Complete!\n".format(item_name))
        except ClientError as be:
            print("CLIENT ERROR: {0}\n".format(be))
        except Exception as e:
            print("Unable to complete multi-part upload: {0}".format(e))


    def main():
    multi_part_upload('570p', 'DB2Backup', BackupFile)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
            main()

Expected Result : the multi_part_upload uploads a File to the link.
```

Comment: is the code you added here inside a function? could you show a snippet of the function definition including the `def` keyword?

Comment: Not sure if this was an error caused by copy pasting, but the indentation of your code in the post is very broken.

Comment: Formatting has been corrected , now it is passing the Variable in the function , I dont seem to be able to do it , although bkp() returns the variable reference for function multi_part_upload : ```/usr/local/bin/python3.6 Script_ICOS_Upload.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Script_ICOS_Upload.py", line 67, in <module>
    main()
  File "Script_ICOS_Upload.py", line 64, in main
    multi_part_upload('570p','DB2Backup',BackupFile)
NameError: name 'BackupFile' is not defined